# connecting MySQL using wamp and hibernate in eclipse

Tags: mysql, eclipse, hibernate, servlets, mysql-connector

```
public class TableDAOImpl implements TableDAO {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory=new Configuration()
        .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
        .buildSessionFactory();

    @Override
    public void save(Table table) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
        try {
            Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(table);
            //  session.getTransaction().commit();
            if (!tx.wasCommitted()){
                tx.commit();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("SAVE: "+e);
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        session.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Table table) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
        try{
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(table);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("UPDATE: "+e);
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        session.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Table table) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.delete(table);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("GET: "+e);
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        session.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public Table get(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Table table=new Table();
        Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
        try{
            final Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
            table= (Table) session.get(Table.class,id);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("SAVE: "+e);
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        } finally {
            if(session != null) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
        session.clear();        
        return table;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Table> list() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<Table> allTables=new ArrayList();
        Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();

        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            org.hibernate.Query query=session.createQuery("FROM Table");
            allTables=((Query) query).getResultList();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("LIST: "+e);
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        session.clear();
        return allTables;
    }
}
```

I am running MySql through wamp and using hibernate and servlet in eclipse. I am 
getting this error
ERROR: HHH000299: Could not complete schema update
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo

Servlet.service() for servlet [com.series.controller.TableController] in context with path [/HibernateProject] threw exception
org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started

And the following exception:
SAVE: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection

I tried finding suitable driver on google but no luck. Please help

Comment: My problem was that my driver was blocked. Right- click on the connector file ->properties->Then the 'unblock ' button in the end on right hand side . Available in General tab

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/dU43N